# dropdown on image click in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the imbalance theme from wpshower.
You can check the demo at http://wpshower.com/demo/?theme=imbalance2.
I want to display a dropdown menu on image click. How to do that in wordpress.
I have done it using javascript and html. The link to it http://pastebin.com/BQtxFbEh. Can anyone tell me how to do it in wordpress.

Any suggestion or solutions plz ? It is urgent!!!

Comment: someone plz help me with this isssue

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what feature from the demo are you trying to replicate? It's not all that clear in your question..

Comment: The image which is displayed (as u can see in the demo) when clicked should display a dropdown.